# Inspecting Detached DOM Tree in Angular application

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-chrome, memory-leaks

Any idea as to why the following are showing up as Detached DOM tree ? 
I am trying to track down a memory leak in my application.

I pulled out these snippets using $0 in the console . In the chrome profiler the containing objects were all highlighted in red meaning that they could not be GC'd or are preventing garbage collection in some way.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-8 ng-scope" ng-if="!ismobile">
      <div>
        <h1 class="ng-binding">{{episodeobj.seriesTitle}}</h1>
        <h2 class="ng-binding">{{episodeobj.titlefull}}</h2>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <h4 class="ng-binding">{{episodeobj.summaryshort}}</h4>
    </div>
```

---

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-8 ng-scope" ng-if="ismobile">
  <div>
    <h1 class="ng-binding">{{episodeobj.seriesTitle}}</h1>
    <h2 class="ng-binding">{{episodeobj.titlefull}}</h2>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <h4 class="ng-binding">{{episodeobj.summaryshort}}</h4>
</div>
```

---

```
<div class="row" style="height: 350px; overflow: hidden; overflow-y: scroll;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" ng-repeat="avi in avatars">
      <a ng-href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault();setavatarid(avi)">
        <img ng-src="{{avi.src}}" width="100%" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

---

```
<a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault;gotoseries()">
  <img ng-src="{{series.imagestyles.style6}}" width="100%" style="border-radius: 20px;">
  <br>
  <h4>More Episodes!</h4>
</a>
```

Comment: I believe you are seeing this because ng-if removes/creates DOM elements (unlike ng-hide/ng-show which just change the display of the elements). See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Comment: @bbird is it possible to run into memory leaks because of this?

Comment: sorry, I should've thought about this a little more carefully. What can happen is if you've got something attaching events to DOM elements outside of angular, say jQuery.on(...) for example, if you don't clean them up yourself angular won't do it for you when directives like ng-if remove them