# Google mobile chrome application crashing

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-chrome, memory-leaks

Can anyone lend any insight a starting point to track down a possible memory leak.
The application runs fine on desktop , but intermittently crashes on chrome for mobile.

However, on desktop I do noticed that my heap snapshot sizes are rather large at times.Routinely I see heap snapshots around 12MB, but other times I see sizes around 60MB.

I've posted a few times about this issue :

- [What does this stack trace mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012717/what-does-this-stack-trace-mean)
- [Inspecting Detached DOM Tree in Angular application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29236962/inspecting-detached-dom-tree-in-angular-application)

I am fairly new to the google memory profiler, I've ran through a few heap snapshots and can't seem to fully track down the culprit that may be causing the leak.

I've notice a large amount of detached nodes that may be preventing the GC from fully cleaning up .

My Application uses, angular, jquery and a few other external libraries.

Here is the website : http://dev.www.amebatv.com/watch/rev3/index.html

If there are any memory profiler gurus out there, please take a look and let me know if you can help

[image]